# multi threading in vsto

Tags: c#, multithreading, vsto

i am facing a issue while trying to put my process in a thread. I want my process in a sub thread and whenever it set flag true value, main thread open UI form. Here is my code

```
public static bool flagThread = false;
    private void btngenerateNew_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        supportThread(sender, e);
        int i=1;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            if (flagThread)
            {
                _Document _doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
                IDesignSpecWord2007.UI_Forms.DisplayError c1 = new IDesignSpecWord2007.UI_Forms.DisplayError(IDSApplyTransformations.ArrErrorsDisp, ref Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, ref _doc);
                Globals.ThisAddIn.DispError = c1;
                c1.Show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void supportThread(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadObject thrdObj = new ThreadObject();
        thrdObj.sender = sender;
        thrdObj.e = e;

        Thread thrStart = new System.Threading.Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(createThread));
        thrStart.Start(thrdObj);
    }
```

i get error "function evaluation disabled because a previous.." when i am trying to access document

```
docm = Globals.ThisAddIn.docm;
```

Comment: where is flagthread set to true?

Comment: @lloydom i set flagThread true on further code when it get error      Ribbon.flagThread = true;
                        IDesignSpecWord2007.UI_Forms.DisplayError c1 = new IDesignSpecWord2007.UI_Forms.DisplayError(IDSApplyTransformations.ArrErrorsDisp, ref Application, ref document);

Comment: Try to obtain an exclusive lock while setting flagThread to true.